# Why can't I access a public string from a method within the same class C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This is my string

```
public string txtEmail;
```

this is the method

```
public void Login(txtEmail, string password){}
```

no code errors, but why can't I access my public txtEmail from the method, they are in the same class.
I searched but I didn't find a reason.
this is the whole class >>

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public String txtEmail;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void Login(txtEmail, String Password)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: could you add more code? This is a bit confusing.

Comment: this is the only code actually , I just started now.

Comment: This code doesn't compile at all. But it looks like your `txtEmail` parameter is hiding the public string.

Comment: like @DavidG mentioned, the public string txtEmail might be hidden behind the method parameter txtEmail. to access the class level (public) txtEmail you'd have to use `this.txtEmail`.

Comment: @nlloyd solution helped alot. solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use the input to `Login()` to populate the public field txtEmail.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public String txtEmail;
    public MainWindow()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void Login(String txtEmail, String Password)
    {
        this.txtEmail = txtEmail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error , txtEmail in login parameters is marked red , missing a type or reference. 
this.txtEmail = txtEmail , is marked green, solution removes "this" and it's still green too.

Comment: Great!!! this fixed it actually I will compare mine to this n see, btw edit
your are missing a semicolon after the last txtEmail word :) Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing "string" in...

```
private void Login(txtEmail, String Password)
{

}
```

Should be...

```
private void Login(string txtEmail, String Password)
{

}
```

That should resolve a compile error. But even then, I am not clear on what your intentions are. E.g. I don't know if you think you're passing the txtEmail property of the class to the Login function or if you're truly trying to pass in an external value.